# Why can someone "Reject and Edit", then make an identical edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I made an edit to resolve incorrect spelling in a title, but it was rejected.

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - **view the
>   revision history to see what should have been changed**.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13643611

After going to the post history to see how the edit, supposedly should have been resolved, I found out that the edit (made by the same person who rejected mine) was identical to my suggestion.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35179108/revisions

The only incentive I can see here is to highjack the 2 points and the credit toward an Archaeologist badge.

Why is this allowed? After doing several edits I've realized that quite a few get arbitrarily rejected, only to find out the person who rejected it makes a similar (if not identical) change immediately.

Comment: "After doing several edits I've realized that quite a few get arbitrarily rejected, only to find out the person who rejected it makes a similar (if not identical) change immediately" - I see 8 rejected edits in your history, and this is the **only** one where it's been rejected and had a similar edit made by someone else.

Comment: Any eligible reviewer at 2k no longer gets reputation from their edits to posts.  So there isn't any hijacking of reputation.  Denial of reputation could still be motivation though.

Comment: @ryanyuyu thanks. I didn't know that about users over 2k.

Comment: @resueman, there have been some edits that took my suggestion and expanded it on it with minor tweaks. Not that big of a deal, so I probably shouldn't have even mentioned it. The only one I really have a complaint about is the blatant copy.

Comment: If the user would not have stepped in then your edit would have been rejected for being too minor.  It was headed that way.  Probably best to focus on the big picture here instead of assuming the user had nefarious purposes in mind, your edit did have the effect you intended.  Consider thanking him for helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from Joe W:

> There is also a feeling that small and minor edits that do not fix everything with the post should not award reputation and people will work to make sure that they do not.

and ryanyuyu mentions this:

> Any eligible reviewer at 2k no longer gets reputation from their edits to posts. So there isn't any hijacking of reputation. Denial of reputation could still be motivation though.

Answer (score 8):

You made what amounts to a two letter edit to the question that is seven months old. Not only that but you did not correct all the errors in the post as I see several others that should have been corrected.

When editing a post you should be making sure you fix all the errors and not just the easy one to see in the title. Until you get the privilege to edit without needing a review these edits take other peoples time by going to the review queue. On top of that they bump old questions to the front page again.

There is also a feeling that small and minor edits that do not fix everything with the post should not award reputation and people will work to make sure that they do not.

Comment: That just raises the point of why did the new editor not then correct the said new mistakes? They should have rejected it and either correctly edited it, or waited until someone else did.

Comment: @Draken Reject and Edit like the user did removes the edit from the queue while just rejecting leaves it in the queue until either 2 more users reject the edit or enough approve it.

Comment: If they believed the said edit should have gone through as it was, reject and edit was not the correct choice by the user

Comment: @Draken I am guessing they believed that reputation should not be awarded for such a trivial edit that did not fix everything in the post.

Comment: Your most recent comment provides a lot more insight and explanation than the actual answer does. But thanks I appreciate your feedback.